# How can I extract font information while isolating the scope of the target font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

(I had to change the title of this question, sorry early viewers.)

I knew all along that I had serious scope issues, but the code was "good enough" until now. My code was working fine for me because I was using fonts that had enough glyphs to cover both keys and values in my table shown in the example. When I started using FontAwesome, I had to face my fears.

1. extracting information about a target font, but typeset info itself in `\normalfont`
2. list glyph slot numbers in `\normalfont` while illustrating each glyph in target font

## Example

The keys/values should all be in `\normalfont`, while values themselves should be from the target font:

```
Font Name: <value from target font>
Type of font: <value from target font>
Number of glyphs: <value from  target font>
Number of features: <value from  target font>
First character: <value from target font>
Last character: <value from target font>

1. <glyph in target font>
2. <glyph in target font>
3. <glyph in target font>
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multicol}
\defaultfontfeatures{Extension=.otf}% Add .otf to \newfontfamily\FA{FontAwesome} fontawesome packagusepackage{fontawesome} % adds defs for easy access to characters
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Add defs for easy access to characters

\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}
\newcommand{\fonttable}[1]{%
    \section{Font: \macroname{#1}}
    \fontinfo{#1}
    #1
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxstep{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1}
    \typeout{XeTeXcountglyphs maxstep is \maxstep} % Prints maxstep to log
    \begin{multicols}{6}
    \foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
        \makebox[3em][l]{\tiny\charstep}%
        \bgroup\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont\textcolor{red}{\XeTeXglyph\charstep}\egroup
        \endgraf
    }%
    \end{multicols}
}%

\newcommand{\fontinfo}[1]{%
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    Font: #1\fontname\font \\
    Type of font: \getfonttype\\
    Number of glyphs: \the\numexpr\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1\relax\\
    Number of features: \the\XeTeXcountfeatures\font\\
    First character: \char\XeTeXfirstfontchar\font{} corresponding to unicode base-10 character \the\XeTeXfirstfontchar\font \\
    Last character: \char\XeTeXlastfontchar\font{} correponding to unicode base-10 character \the\XeTeXlastfontchar\font \\
    \end{minipage}}
}%

\newcommand{\getfonttype}{%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{0}{%
        \hologo{TeX} font (a legacy TFM-based font)
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{1}{%
        AAT font
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{2}{%
        OpenType
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{3}{%
        Graphite
        }%
        {}%
}%

\begin{document}
\fonttable{\normalfont}
\fonttable{\FA}
\end{document}
```

## Output Emphasizing Scope Problem

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to confine the font selection only where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multicol}

\defaultfontfeatures{Extension=.otf}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}

\newcommand{\fonttable}[1]{%
  \section{Font: \macroname{#1}}
  \fontinfo{#1}
  \begin{multicols}{6}
  #1%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxstep{\the\XeTeXcountglyphs\font-1}
  \typeout{XeTeXcountglyphs maxstep is \maxstep} % Prints maxstep to log
  \foreach \charstep in {1,...,\maxstep}{%
    \makebox[20pt][l]{\normalfont\tiny\charstep}%
    \textcolor{red}{\XeTeXglyph\charstep}
    \endgraf
  }
  \end{multicols}
}

\newcommand{\fontinfo}[1]{%
  \fbox{%
    \begingroup#1\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\fontinfofont{\the\font}}\x
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      Font: \fontname\fontinfofont \\
      Type of font: \getfonttype\\
      Number of glyphs: \the\numexpr\XeTeXcountglyphs\fontinfofont-1\relax\\
      Number of features: \the\XeTeXcountfeatures\fontinfofont\\
      First character: {\fontinfofont\char\XeTeXfirstfontchar\font}
        corresponding to unicode base-10 character
        \the\XeTeXfirstfontchar\fontinfofont \\
      Last character: {\fontinfofont\char\XeTeXlastfontchar\font}
        correponding to unicode base-10 character
        \the\XeTeXlastfontchar\fontinfofont \\
      \end{minipage}%
    }
}

\newcommand{\getfonttype}{%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{0}{%
        \hologo{TeX} font (a legacy TFM-based font)
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{1}{%
        AAT font
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{2}{%
        OpenType
        }%
        {}%
    \IfEq{\the\XeTeXfonttype\font}{3}{%
        Graphite
        }%
        {}%
}

\begin{document}

\fonttable{\normalfont}
\fonttable{\FA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\begingroup#1\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\fontinfofont{\the\font}}\x` do?

We open a group, where the font selection is executed; thus in the group `\font` will refer to the font to be tested and `\the\font` will expand to the control sequence that selects it. We need to expand `\the\font`, so `\edef` is the tool; the `\x` temporary control sequence is defined to expand to

```
\endgroup\def\fontinfofont{<the needed control sequence>}
```

so that executing it will close the group and undo the font selection (and remove the definition for `\x` as well); however `<the needed control sequence>` is already in the replacement text for the definition when it will be executed.

Comment: The code you posted creates many fontspec errors. `Missing character: There is no p in font [FontAwesome.otf]/OT:!` In my real document, it creates errors for nearly the entire Latin alphabet. Do you know why and how to fix this? Thanks for the explanation below by the way.